# Windows server 2008 OR 2008 R2 SP1 for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Could anyone suggest me on this- we have sharepoint 2007 running on win server-2008 64bit

and we are about to upgrade to 2010 sharepoint, problem is do we keep the 2008 64bit as is or

upgrade to R2 and install SP 2010 on it.

obviously R2 must be more reliable than 2008 but just asking if we can we just upgrade

2008 to R2 with out a new server?

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Consider

- Have the 2008 installation been unreliable and if so is it really windows? If it has it might be time to buy some new hardware
- Are you worried about the support and update cycle for windows 2008? Obviously the ones for R2 will extend further into the future

However, If it's a dedicated SharePoint server machine that has been running just fine I see little or no reason to upgrade to R2.

If you choose to keep your server upgrading to Windows 2008 R2 remember to install the sp2 for SharePoint 2007 (wss3) BEFORE you upgrade.

Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Service Pack 2 (SP2) - English
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=79bada82-c13f-44c1-bdc1-d0447337051b&displaylang=en

Comment: when we upgrade to R2 from server 2008 x64, will the applications and data get carried across without any issue or do we need to re-setup everything from scracth?

Comment: also my MOSS version is 12.0.0.6514, is this the latest version and includes WSS 3.0 SP2?

Comment: The version 12.0.0.6421 included the SP2 so you should be good. There are however some later builds than 6515, your build was released in august 2009.

Comment: You might want to do some more reading about upgrading. Check technet http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc303309(office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

When i first started doing sp2010, i used windows2008. That was a real pain, things were just buggy. As soon as i moved to r2, no more bugs. So i would say go with r2. It also means you can install r2 sp1.

Comment: when we upgrade to R2 from server 2008 x64, will the applications and data get carried across without any issue or do we need to re-setup everything from scratch?